# reverse animation working on chrome, ff etc. but not in safari

Tags: css, animation, safari, webkit

I can't get the reverse animation to work on safari. Does somebody know why the reverse animation (globalnavholder.searchhide) is running well on every browser except on safari? I found out, that safari sometimes does not like reverse animations or that this is not supported, but it won't even work if I set up an own reverse animation for safari. The origin animation (#globalnavholder.searchopen) is running well on safari.

```
@-webkit-keyframes list-searchshow {
0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1);
}
100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%) translateY(106px);
    transform: translateY(-100%) translateY(106px);
 }
}

@keyframes list-searchshow {
0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1)
}
100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%) translateY(106px);
    transform: translateY(-100%) translateY(106px);
 }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
 #globalnavholder .content .mobile-nav-holder {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 80px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 48px;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: visibility 0s linear 1s;
    transition: visibility 0s linear 1s;
 }

 #menustate:checked ~ #globalnavholder .content .mobile-nav-holder,
 #menustate:target ~ #globalnavholder .content .mobile-nav-holder {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
 }

 #globalnavholder.searchshow .content .mobile-nav-holder {
    bottom: auto;
    -webkit-animation: list-searchshow 800ms both;
    animation: list-searchshow 800ms both;
 }

 #globalnavholder.searchopen .content .mobile-nav-holder {
    display: none;
 }

 #globalnavholder.searchhide .mobile-nav-holder {
    bottom: auto;
    -webkit-animation: list-searchshow 800ms reverse both;
    animation: list-searchshow 800ms reverse both;
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a complete example, that demonstrates the issue? Also, which version of Safari?

Comment: @MrLister I could do so, the problem is the markup is huge (inc. jQuery etc.) and I found out that it is working on jsfiddle as I begun to set it up for you. I have no clue why it is working there, but not on my live site. However, would you mind to have a closer look? Maybe you'll find an error if I could send you the live site on a private way somehow, since it should not be published up to now and jsfiddle is not able to demonstrate the thing. If you don't have any time left, no worries mate! :)